# python - Parsing data from binary file using structs

Tags: python, struct, binary, unpack

I have a save game file that I am trying to parse out all of the characters attributes by reading the file using hex offsets. I'm able to get all strings out properly since that plain text but I am having issues with parsing the binary portions that I am working with.

I'm pretty sure that I'm reading in the right data but when I unpack the string I am getting unexpected (incorrect) output

The file I'm working with is www.retro-gaming-world.com/SAVE.DAT

```
import struct
infile = open('SAVE.DAT','rb')
try:
    buff = infile.read()
finally:
    infile.close

infile.seek(0x00,0)
print "Save Signature: " + infile.read(0x18)
print "Save Version: " + str(struct.unpack('>i',buff[0x18:0x18+4])[0])
infile.seek(0x1C,0)
print "The letter R: " + infile.read(0x01)
infile.seek(0x1D,0)
print "Character Name: " + infile.read(0x20)
infile.seek(0x3D,0)
print "Save Game Name: " + infile.read(0x1E)
print "Save game day: " + str(struct.unpack('>i',buff[0x5B:0x5B+4])[0])
print "Save game month: " + str(struct.unpack('>i',buff[0x5D:0x5D+4])[0])
print "Save game year: " + str(struct.unpack('>i', buff[0x5F:0x5F+4])[0])
```

I'm having two different issues, either the wrong data is returned or when I try to unpack some of the fields I get an error that the string isn't long enough, I can read in more but the day month and year are only 2 and 4 bytes respectively and are integers, I'm not sure I'm going about this the right way, I believe I'm fetching the right fields but think I am unpacking or handling the data incorrectly some where if not completely.

version should return 0100
day should return 21
month should return 09
year should return 2013

What exactly am I getting wrong hrere, is there another way or a better way to go about parsing the fields from the binary?

Comment: started looking into it; i figured a typo in the last line; sturct--> struct

Comment: I fixed the typo in the code but otherwise haven't made any progress in understanding what it is I'm getting wrong causing me to get incorrect output on my fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is, that although the values are of integer type, they only have the length of 2, being an unsigned short in C. Thus, you have to read them as

`struct.unpack('>H',buff[0x5B:0x5B+2])[0])`

and so on. signed or unsigned does not seem to make a difference here. If available, check the documentation of the save file, it should be denoted there which is appropriate. If not, good luck trying (`itertools` can be helpful).

For more details of types, check the table on [the Python documentation for structs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters)

As a big fan of Fallout 1 and 2 I do wish you good luck and lots of success with the project (-;

Comment: In an effort to get back into coding I took on the project of writing a character editor since I'm playing through it gives me incentive to learn this more complicated stuff. Just can't seem to read the binary fields right. Curiously I'm also getting the following error now Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seek2", line 19, in <module>
    print "Save game day: " + str(struct.unpack('>h',buff[0x5B:0x5B+4])[0])
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2
even though the length of the string is 4 :/

Comment: see above, you used +4 meaning reading four byte instead of two, like I did in the example above. To avoid these issues, you could go with something like: `s='>H'; struct.unpack(s, buff[.x..:.x..+struct.calcsize(s)])[0])`

Comment: Sheez I should probably sleep I didn't even notice, I made the change and now I get what I want.f1nk@laptop:~/Documents/SAVEGAME/SLOT06$ python seek2
Save Signature: FALLOUT SAVE FILE
Save Version: 65536
The letter R: R
Character Name: f1nk
Save Game Name: church
String lenght: 4
STring:  
Save game day: 22
String lenght: 4
Save game month: 9
Save game year: 2013
Just that one little detail that was screwing every thing up. You are a magic man or woman which ever the case maybe. Now that every things working I can have a functional character/save game editor done in no time. Thanks again.

Comment: "Magic" comes with practice - I have reverse engineered some files and thus know some of the common errors by now (;